# Crosscompile Python bdist_wininst executeables

Tags: python, cpu-architecture

I'm using a 64bit Windows machine with 64bit python3. I need to build a installable package for a windows 32bit machine and stumbled upon the cross compile feature of the bdist feature: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html

I'm using a setup.py like this:

```
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='1.0',
      description='Some Description',
      install_requires=['requests'],
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      packages=[''],
      entry_points = {'console_scripts': ['somescript = foobar:main']},
      )
```

And build the install packages like so:

```
python setup.py build --plat-name=win32 bdist_wininst --user-access-control auto
python setup.py build --plat-name=win-amd64 bdist_wininst --user-access-control auto
```

In both cases I get the correct executeable format for the specified architecture but the defined console_script `somescript` was not executeable after installation.
The python documentation says that I need to crosscompile the whole python package for windows - but I'am uncertain if this is even necessary because the installer was for the right architecture and I got no error message while the build process. 
Is there something wrong with the command? Do I really need to crosscompile or is it sufficiant to have a second 32bit installation of python?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out this is a reported bug https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/253

The setuptools do only check for the OS architecture and ignore the plat-name string for the installation of scripts.

Workaround (until this issue is closed): Use the target architecture for building the wininst.